# ¿Es posible setear y limitar la memoria PHP diferente en el Backend y Frontend de Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

es mi primer pregunta en el Foro, así que aquí vamos. Tengo un sitio Wordpress con Elementor y Elementor pro y necesito tener disponibilidad de RAM alta en el backend, pero no así en el Frontend. Concretamente necesito que el Back tenga 1500M de RAM y el Front 384M.
Estuve investigando y descubrí 2 variables del wp-config que me permitirían setear esos valores:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '384');
define('WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1500');
```

El tema es que a pesar de que agrego estas variables, las mismas no limitan como yo deseo el uso de la RAM en el Front de Wordpress a 384, sino que tienen disponible la RAM que defino en el php.ini del Apache (en este caso 1500M).

Alguien podría indicarme si estoy haciendo algo mal o simplemente esas variables no sirven para limitar sino únicamente para extender el límite de la memoria que usa por default Wordpress?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Esas variables solo hacen que haya un minimo y maximo de RAM que la APP puede usar, no se si se pueda limitar el fronted y backend, si fuesen dos instalaciones separadas podrías, pero al estar ambas en la misma APP se vuelve complicado, después de todo, como sabe WORDPRESS que está en el fronted o en el backend, tomando en cuenta que incluso en el fronted, el backend sigue haciendo su trabajo, como el CRON o WP Hearth.

Comment: Veo que hay diferentes opciones, creo que las mas comunes es manejar de forma correcta `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` y `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT`, también podrías intentar usar archivos como **user.ini** y **php.ini** y declarar la variable `memory_limit`, de forma adicional he conseguido algo que podría ser útil que es un *plugin* para para manejar el limite de memoria desde el panel de apps de Wordpress o algo así: [change-memory-limit](https://wordpress.org/plugins/change-memory-limit/#description).

Comment: gracias @user327285, pero creo que eso no soluciona mi problema, ya que lo que yo necesito es setear el ram máximo de cada proceso para el frontend y el backend por separado y no lo estoy logrando con esas 2 variables. Entiendo que el plugin hace lo mismo pero sin editar el wp-config manualmente.

Comment: @JefferzonBol muchas gracias, creo que efectivamente no se puede hacer lo que estoy intentando.

Comment: en principio revisaría el stack de plugins, instala [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/es/) con `wp plugin list --status=active` te da la lista.

Comment: @aloMalbarez gracias. No conocía wp-cli. En este caso puntual, ¿para qué me serviría revisar el stack de plugins instalados? (tengo acceso normal al admin de WP).

Comment: es para revisar la lista y ver si hay algún sospechoso de estar o interfiriendo con el generador de imagenes de elementor ( recorte/ thumbnails ) o armando shortcodes de manera ineficiente ( sin transients / con selects y joins sin usar el api / usando tablas sin indices ). el proceso de imagenes y las consultas no optimizadas son por lo general lo que consume tanta memoria.

Comment: para optimizar el uso de memoria de la db: en el backend podes usar algun plugin que reporte el tamaño de cada table y que plugin la creo. también considerar que ha habido historicamente una insana costumbre de guardar cosas en options con autoload o usar meta indiscriminadamente para cosas que o necesitan una tabla propia ( correctamente indexada ) o son datos que no necesariamente hay que calcular en cada load . del lado del terminal [mysqltuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) luego de varios dias de trafico te puede dar un par de pistas de q puede estar pasando

Comment: @aloMalbarez ok, muchas gracias por la info!!

Comment: Quizá no deberías depender de un plugin que requiera tanta memoria, a no ser que el sitio se dedique a cosas como transmisión de imágenes en vivo desde la Estación Espacial Internacional o cosas así :). ¿Por qué se requiere toda esa memoria? Si necesitas hacer procesos costosos, puedes ir a un nivel más bajo para hacerlos sin demasiado costo para el servidor y si es para ofrecerlo a otros administradores con menos nivel de acceso, entonces podrías pensar en programar tu propio código y ofrecerlo en el panel de administración. Sí, hablo de escribir tu propio plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress corre sobre PHP
PHP significa **PHP HyperText Preprocessor** (es una recursión). ¿Qué significa esto? Que en su origen PHP nació como un motor para preprocesar texto interpolando variables. Como quien dice, lo que hoy se hace con Blade o Twig.

Imagínate que tienes un archivo index.html en tu servidor. Su contenido es estático. Cuando lo cargas el webserver sirve su contenido usando una cantidad infinitesimal de memoria.

Ahora imagínate que un request tuviera dos partes. Primero tú envías al servidor ciertos parámetros. El servidor modifica el contenido de index.html para satisfacer esos parámetros. Luego, en una segunda fase, cuando PHP ya hizo su trabajo y cerró el request, tú cargas ese index.html estático y ves el contenido que PHP escribió en él.

En este último ejemplo, tú no tienes contacto con PHP, sólo con el index.html. **¿Dónde está la memoria del frontend? No existe**. Cuando PHP empieza a llenar el contenido del index.html ya terminó su cómputo. En la vida real, en vez de volcar la salida al archivo te la manda a ti directamente.

Si todos estamos de acuerdo en que la memoria de PHP se gasta en el backend, y es el browser el encargado de gastar memoria en renderizar el frontend, prosigamos.

Si lo que tú quieres hacer es asignar una cantidad de memoria distinta a wordpress para renderizar **las páginas del panel de administración versus las páginas visibles del sitio**, eso es otra cosa muy distinta. Ambos conjuntos son backend, sólo son secciones distintas.

Puedes manipular el comportamiento de wordpress usando hooks. Lo importante es saber qué hook se gatilla en cada sección y en qué parte del ciclo de vida.

Para asignar un comportamiento en particular al panel de administración yo creo que te serviría `admin_init` . Este

```
function aumentar_memoria_en_el_panel() {
     ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'aumentar_memoria_en_el_panel', 1 );
```

Eso puedes ponerlo en el `functions.php` de tu theme, o hacerte un `mu_plugin`

Pero... antes de que te preccipites a copiar y pegar ese código, recuerda que el límite de memoria de PHP es por worker thread. Un worker no tiene idea de que existen los otros, y no hay tal cosa como un balanceo de recursos centralizado. Con ese setting un worker recibe un request, se autoasigna 256M y termina por enviar una respuesta. Si tienes 100 usuarios concurrentes eso no resiste. (dudo que tengas 100 administradores, pero se entiende el ejemplo).

Si usas ese hook, éste nunca se ejecutará al visitar páginas del frontend público. Sin embargo, es posible que en otros hooks del ciclo de vida de un request del panel la cantidad de memoria vuelva a ser modificada por algún plugin.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu detallada respuesta. Finalmente abandonamos el constructor visual que estábamos usando (elementor) porque consumía una cantidad enorme de recursos. No obstante, conseguimos mejorar el funcionamiento optimizando la base de datos, que tenía una gran cantidad de tablas basura creadas por plugins que venían instalador por defecto.